# Converting calendar value to DateTime gives InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, sql-server

So i have an application which uses a calendar to select a date and when im trying to save the inputted data to the SQL server i get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar' to type 'System.IConvertible'. at System.Convert.ToDateTime(Object value) at FriendsWithPaws.Default.okButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\COMP 1551 COURSEWORK\FriendsWithPaws\FriendsWithPaws\AddPet.aspx.cs:line 44

This is part of line 44 (with the error).. here i have assumed the `Convert.ToDateTime()` to be the fix...:

```
+ Convert.ToDateTime(dateRescuedCalendar) + "', '"
```

[Screenshot of Error on webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldilQ.png)

[Screenshot of SQL server data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H94xS.png)

Comment: Whatever control you are using, it should expose a property of the selected date (either `string` or `DateTime`). Pretty much the same as TextBox.Text to read/write a textbox content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to convert your actual calendar object to a date time.

Probably `dateRescuedCalendar` has some kind of "value", or maybe "selectedDate" property that contains the actual date that was selected by the user.

Comment: The property is called SelectedDate: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate?view=netframework-4.7.2